# Pick two items from a list based on a condition

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Here is the simplified version of the problem ;)

Given following list,

```
my_list = [{'name': 'apple', 'type': 'fruit'},
    {'name': 'orange', 'type': 'fruit'},
    {'name': 'mango', 'type': 'fruit'},
    {'name': 'tomato', 'type': 'vegetable'},
    {'name': 'potato', 'type': 'vegetable'},
    {'name': 'leek', 'type': 'vegetable'}]
```

How to pick only two items from the list for a particular type to achieve following?

```
filtered = [{'name': 'apple', 'type': 'fruit'},
    {'name': 'orange', 'type': 'fruit'},
    {'name': 'tomato', 'type': 'vegetable'},
    {'name': 'leek', 'type': 'vegetable'}]
```

Comment: Have you... tried *anything* to solve this? If yes - show it, and your thoughts about your attempt. If not - why not?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the requirements for time and space complexity?

Comment: I thought and attempted sorting the list first based on the condition using something like `sorted_data = sorted(selected_data, key=lambda k: k['type'])` then going line by line to check and add it to another list... but not so happy about it. I think there may be smarter way to do it. What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the answers but why downvote? Is my question unclear or not useful? It is useful for me. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to group the elements of your list based on `type` and the grab only the first 2 elements from each group.

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> f = lambda k: k['type']
>>> n = 2
>>> res = [grp for _,grps in groupby(sorted(my_list, key=f), f) for grp in list(grps)[:n]]
>>> pprint(res)
[{'name': 'apple', 'type': 'fruit'},
 {'name': 'orange', 'type': 'fruit'},
 {'name': 'tomato', 'type': 'vegetable'},
 {'name': 'potato', 'type': 'vegetable'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can `groupby` then pick the first 2:

```
from itertools import groupby

a = [list(j)[:2] for i, j in groupby(my_list, key = lambda x: x['type'])]

print(a)
[[{'name': 'apple', 'type': 'fruit'}, {'name': 'orange', 'type': 'fruit'}],
 [{'name': 'tomato', 'type': 'vegetable'},
  {'name': 'potato', 'type': 'vegetable'}]]


sum(a,[])
Out[299]: 
[{'name': 'apple', 'type': 'fruit'},
 {'name': 'orange', 'type': 'fruit'},
 {'name': 'tomato', 'type': 'vegetable'},
 {'name': 'potato', 'type': 'vegetable'}]
```